# What is a "stub" in Intellij Cursive?

Tags: cursive

The following message from time to time appears in Cursive:

`"Your project requires namespaces which need stubs to be generated"`

When I first saw that I thought it was something along the lines of generating code, in the way rails might generate code stubs for you. Obviously I don't want that, this is clojure, so I pressed ok anyway, and it seemed not to do anything. So what does this message mean?

What exactly (or even approximately) is a "stub" is in this context?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cursive User Guide https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/macros.html
Stubs are "source files containing empty function stubs which it can index for use in the editor."

Comment: Thanks. That part of the manual goes some way to explaining it. Question for the cursive authors if they read this: it seems a mystery why the user is actually prompted about this. Can't cursive make the decision internally when stubs are required? To make the point: why would I ever want to *not* press OK to "generate stubs"?

Comment: Probably you always want to, it enables static analysis. Maybe you don't want to create new files at some point (switch to checkout to a branch or something).